# C printf %d incorrect value with leading zeros?

Tags: c, printf, constants, system-calls

The C function printf seems to print different values depending on whether or not leading zeros are present.

I was trying to determine the numerical values for the mode argument in the Linux 'open' system call.
`printf("mode:%d\n",S_IRWXU);`
`printf("mode:%d\n",00700);`

both gave me 448, while

`printf("mode:%d\n",700);` gives me 700, as I would expect from both.

What is going on here?

I am using gcc (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.5) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: Leading `0` is for octal.

Comment: @Abraham McIlvaine  Consider the output of this call. printf("mode:%#o\n", 448);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A numerical constant with one or more leading zeros is an **octal constant**, while one without a leading zero is a **decimal constant** and one with a leading `0x` is a **hexadecimal constant**.  This holds in any context, whether the value is passed to `printf` or any other function.

In the case of `printf`, you're using the `%d` format specifier which prints the value in decimal.  If you pass in an octal constant, you'll see the decimal value of that octal number.  In this example, 0700b8 == 7 * 8^2 + 0 * 8^1 + 0 * 8^0 == 7 * 64 == 448b10

If you're dealing with file permissions, those values are typically denoted as octal, so you should always use a leading 0 with those.